# Extract text between special characters in bash

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, ksh

I have a long list of lines in a file and I want to extract the field name from this syntax...

```
decimal('\x01', maximum_length=10) trnsfl_err_tkt_trshold_1002 = NULL("\0"); /* Added for phase 3B May release INTERNAL VARIABLE*/
```

So for that line I want to extract trnsfl_err_tkt_trshold_1002 with no blankspaces

Here is a sample of the file with just a few lines:

```
decimal('\x01', maximum_length=4, sign_reserved) cld_sc = NULL("\0") /* Added for Phase 3B 20180104 BF */;
datetime("YYYYMMDDHH24MISS.NNNNNN")("\x01") cld_sc_ts = NULL("\0") /* Added for Phase 3B 20180104 BF */;
decimal('\x01', maximum_length=4, sign_reserved) cld_seg_cd = NULL("\0") /* Added for Phase 3B 20180104 BF */;
utf8 string('\x01', maximum_length=4) actn_rqst_cd = NULL("\0") /* Added for Phase 3B 20180125 Gurka */;
decimal('\x01', maximum_length=1) hram_prrty_rank_elig_in = NULL("\0"); /* INTERNAL VARIABLES */
decimal('\x01', maximum_length=4, sign_reserved) tcli_wk_excl_pass_in = NULL("\0"); /* Added for phase 3B May release*/
decimal('\x01', maximum_length=4, sign_reserved) tcli_wk_excl_rsn_cd = NULL("\0"); /* Added for phase 3B May release*/
date("YYYYMMDD")('\x01') rltm_last_perm_cr_lmt_updt_dt = NULL("\0") ; /* Added for phase 3B */
date("YYYYMMDD")('\x01') clinc_cmpgn_dt = NULL("\0"); /* Added for phase 3B May release*/
decimal('\x01', maximum_length=11, sign_reserved) clinc_rank_ordr_nb = NULL("\0"); /* Added for phase 3B May release*/
```

Expected output would be:

```
cld_sc  
cld_sc_ts  
cld_seg_cd  
actn_rqst_cd  
hram_prrty_rank_elig_in  
tcli_wk_excl_pass_in  
tcli_wk_excl_rsn_cd  
rltm_last_perm_cr_lmt_updt_dt  
clinc_cmpgn_dt  
clinc_rank_ordr_nb
```

Comment: how do you locate that line?

Comment: Well it's a file on my filesystem that has a ton of lines. It's basically a DDL showing all field names with their data types and their max lengths. What I'm trying to do is extract just the field name. So max length and data type will be different across a lot of the lines

Comment: So in other words you want to extract the last token before the first equal sign?

Comment: @karakfa Or before the second in a line with `maximum_length=1`.

Answer (score 1):

So in other words you want to extract the last token before the first equal sign

```
$ sed -E 's/.* ([^ ]+) =.*/\1/' file
cld_sc
cld_sc_ts
cld_seg_cd
actn_rqst_cd
hram_prrty_rank_elig_in
tcli_wk_excl_pass_in
tcli_wk_excl_rsn_cd
clinc_cmpgn_dt
clinc_rank_ordr_nb
```

Comment: for some reason it is failing for this scenario...

    decimal('\x01', maximum_length=1) tcli_mkt_sel_in  = NULL("\0"); /* Added for phase 3B May release INTERNAL VARIABLE*/

Comment: Ahhhh I see why. Because there is an extra space before the equal sign. Is there a way of ignoring that. So if there are multiple spaces it will still consider it acceptable ?

Comment: add `+` before the equal sign.

Comment: You should ignore the comment: `echo "type(foo) extract_me = NULL /* comment with an = in it */" | sed -r 's/.* ([^ ]+) =.*/\1/' `